# How to display a specific UIViewController when a push notification is received and tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to display a specific UIViewController when a push notification is received and the user tap on that notification.  I made some research and tried a few things without success.

I tried the following code, it works on UIAlertController but it didn't display the specific UIViewController I wanted.  Please help me out.  I am using Xcode 6.3.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    if(apsInfo) {

        UIStoryboard *myStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        notificationViewController *nvc = [myStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notificationViewController"];

        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:nvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

You could create a 'Router' object that handle the notification payload, and pass that object from ViewController to ViewController, building the navigation stack step by step.

[Here is a link to a sample project](https://github.com/simondec/simple-routing-example) I made to illustrate that concept.  For the sake of the demo, the 'Router' is built following a call to `buildNavigationStack` in `application:application handleOpenURL:`, but you could easily change that to use the userInfo dictionary received in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`.

Comment: Dear @Rufel many users have implement this and its working in mostly all the apps who are using push notifications which directly redirect to another view when user client on that notification message please tell the reference code.

Comment: @onestopappsolution: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

For this need, I create a `UIViewController` variable called `currentViewController` in my AppDelegate class or my Singleton class if it exists in the project.

For every VC created, I add the following line inside the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`:

```
[(myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setCurrentViewController:self];
```

This way the VC being shown on the screen is always kept in an ivar.

So in `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` or where ever you are presenting the `alertViewController` you can present or push your new VC easily.

```
[self.currentViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Full Detail Solution:**
In this approach the critical and tricky part is setting the `currentViewController` in a singleton class. Rest will be very straight forward.

Create Singleton Class:

```
//CapsHelper.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CAPSHelper : NSObject
{

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController * currentViewController;

+ (instancetype)sharedHelpers;
```

---

```
//CapsHelper.m
#import "CAPSHelper.h"
@interface CAPSHelper ()

@end

@implementation CAPSHelper

@synthesize currentViewController;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods
+ (instancetype) sharedHelpers
{
    static CAPSHelper *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

Lets say you have around 10 viewcontrollers in your app called `VC1`, `VC2`, .., `VC10` etc. In each VC's `viewWillAppear:animated:`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[CAPSHelper sharedHelpers] setCurrentViewController:self]
}
```

Or if this seems like lots of repetition, you can create a new class and override `viewWillAppear:animated:` and you wont have trouble trying to remember adding above to new VC's you will create in the future.

At this moment we are all set, every time a VC is being presented to the screen, we are holding it in a variable called `currentViewController`, and it is accessible from everywhere by importing `#import "CAPSHelper.h"`

```
//AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CAPSHelper.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    if(apsInfo)
    {
        if([[CAPSHelper sharedHelpers] currentViewController])
        {
            //UIViewController * pushNotificationViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] ..... This is your specific VC which you want to present when a PN is recieved..
            [[[CAPSHelper sharedHelpers] currentViewController] presentViewController:pushNotificationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    if(apsInfo) 
    {
        if([[CAPSHelper sharedHelpers] currentViewController])
        {
            //UIViewController * pushNotificationViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] ..... This is your specific VC which you want to present when a PN is recieved..
            [[[CAPSHelper sharedHelpers] currentViewController] presentViewController:pushNotificationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please write down the helping source code in more details i am very thankful i like your approach and going to accept the answer just little more help for the mode code its better if you write down step by step metods which works well in approved app. Thanks

Comment: Hope this helps, thats how I do the same thing you are trying to do in my App